# How to assign div 2 display properties?

Tags: html, css

I want to assign a div 2 display properties, I'm not sure what the correct syntax is...

```
#div2 {
  display:none;inline-block;
 }
```

What is the correct way to do this?

UPDATE:

```
#div2 {
  display:none;
 }

$(function() {
  $("#div1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#div2").css('display', 'inline-block');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $("#div2").css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

Comment: there is no way to do this, the last will override the first. What do you want to do?

Comment: this is like i want to be visible and invisible at the same time.

Comment: the div2 should be hidden, but when the user hovers over a div1, div2 should show right next to div1..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only set one value at a time to the `display` property. In this case, the `display: none` will cause the div to not be rendered at all, so the `inline-block` would be totally irrelevant here.

I assume you want to somehow toggle the visibility using javascript. This requires you to toggle the display property between `none` and `inline-block`. As I said, you can always just have one value here.

Comment: I'm using jquery, I can toggle between none and inline-block~ thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this as **Sotiris** said. Just like you can't set two different background-color.

Try to use jQuery (or native js) for this.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: thanks for the link~ I've updated my code, but this doesn't seem to work.. what am I missing?